# Automate Postfix instalaltion with debconf-set-selections?

Tags: debian, postfix

I'm currently trying to automate my Postfix installation and most things work really... but I can't seem to stop postfix-policyd asking for the MySQL root password.

Here is what I got so far:

> echo 'dbconfig-common postfix-policyd/dbconfig-install boolean false' | debconf-set-selections
>
> echo 'postfix-policyd postfix-policyd/dbconfig-install boolean false' | debconf-set-selections
>
> echo 'postfix-policyd postfix-ploicyd/internal/skip-preseed boolean false' | debconf-set-selections
>
> echo 'dbconfig-common dbconfig-common/internal/skip-preseed boolean false' | debconf-set-selections
>
> echo 'postfix-policyd postfix-policyd/dbconfig-upgrade boolean false' | debconf-set-selections
>
> echo 'postfix-policyd/dbconfig-reinstall boolean false' | debconf-set-selections
>
> echo 'dbconfig-common dbconfig-reinstall boolean false' | debconf-set-selections
>
> echo "postfix-policyd postfix-policyd/internal/reconfiguring boolean false" | debconf-set-selections

It seems postfix-policyd just ignores the

> postfix-policyd
> postfix-policyd/dbconfig-install
> boolean false

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my script I disable the interactive frontend first:
`export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`

Then I set al the preferences, f.e.:
`postconf -e "mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, ${NETWORK_CIDR}"`

You can then re-enable it by unsetting it:
`unset DEBIAN_FRONTEND`

Or, you can make it very easy by just running this command:
`DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install postfix-policyd`

Comment: Oh man, this is awesome.  Works like a charm! +1 for you!

Answer (score 1):

To set the MySQL password you need to do the following for your script:

```
ADMIN_PASS=YourPassword

#MySql settings
echo "mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password password $ADMIN_PASS" \
  | debconf-set-selections

echo "mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password_again password $ADMIN_PASS" \
  | debconf-set-selections
```

Just change the numbers for the version of MySQL